# Web crawler for extracting and parsing data and saving it to DB

Tags: php, web-crawler

I wish to copy the content of some website into a local database for a further personalized search. I know that I have to use a crawler and I found some good references about scrapy.

My question is that you know any good crawler written in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/). Give it a try and let us know your thoughts!